# php7.4 error PHP Fatal error: Unable to start pcre module in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, php-7.4

when I run the php -v command I get this error,
php version 7.4 | 7.3, there are no problems on version 7.2

---

gcc version 7.5.0 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)

Comment: how did you install the php 7.4/7.3 and the pcre module? Was there a php 7.2 installed before that? did you just replace the php files, but not the modules? did you compile the php 7.3/7.4 or you used pre compiled version for the install?

Comment: sudo apt-get install php7.4 php7.4-fpm

Comment: Not sure, but maybe jit is not enabled for the pcre2 module

Comment: ok, how to enable it?

Comment: --enable-jit during the configuration at the start of the compilation process. The reason I'm not so sure, is because you are using a pre-built package.
What is the output of php -i | grep jit

Comment: ✘ user@HP ~  php -i | grep jit
PHP Fatal error:  Unable to start pcre module in Unknown on line 0

Answer (score 3):

`cd /usr/local/lib` 
and then
`rm libpcre*` 
It worked fine for me